# How to animate translation and height at the same time in iOS

Tags: ios, animation

I have this code that is Xamarin.iOS.

```
UIView.Animate(
    1.0,
    () => View.Frame = new CGRect(0, View.Frame.Y - 30, 100, View.Frame.Height + 40);
    null
);
```

I'm animating Y translation and height increase. Only the translation is animating but the height is increased without animation :(

The fact that is Xamarin is not relevant, I don't think this is a Xamarin specific problem so the answer could be in C#, Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: you mean it is enough if I provided an animation using pure swift?

Comment: @Mohammad Bashir Sidani: yes. Swift would be enough if works :)

Comment: Please try thisUIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [.repeat, .curveEaseOut, .autoreverse], animations: {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width:0, height:0)
    }, completion: nil)

Comment: It will make your view go to 0 wodth 0 height but is will show you that both the y and height are animating same time

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [.repeat, .curveEaseOut, .autoreverse], animations: {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: newX, y:newY, width:newWidth, height:newHeight)
    }, completion

: nil)
```

Comment: What's the difference with my code? Could you explain why this would work?

Comment: In your code set the new width and height to x,y,widt,height, all to 0, is the 2 animations (height and origin) animating?

Comment: if I change x, y, width and height to 0, only translation is animated. height and width is converted automatically to 0 without any animation

Comment: I think it is an issue with the xamarin code. In your animation try having 2 lines of code, one to change the origins only and the second to change the width and the height. If this did not work, then do 2 animations under each other and get back to me

Comment: Found the answer, it was was related with child subviews layout

Comment: Great! If you found my answer helpful in any matter please up vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. The problem was related to add animation option `UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews` to allow child views to animate in sync with the parent.

```
UIView.Animate(
    1.0, 
    0, 
    UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews,
    () => View.Frame = new CGRect(0, View.Frame.Y - 30, 100, View.Frame.Height + 40),
    null
);
```